# Django UnitTest - Setting session variable

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I have a Django unit test class that is based on django_webtest.WebTest, and I can't find a proper way to set a session variable during the test. I have tried the following, but I don't work

```
from django_webtest import WebTest
class TestMyTests(WebTest):
    def test_my_tesst(self):
       ... 
       self.app.session['var1'] = 'val1'
       ...
```

Comment: what is django_webtest why aren't you using the standard test tools?

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11475

Answer (score 9):

That is generally what [Client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client) is for. It has access to the session data. I can't speak for `django_webtest`, since that's an outside library for django, but internally for unittesting, you can access and set session data like so:

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client

class TestMyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_my_test(self):
        ...
        session = self.client.session
        session['somekey'] = 'test'
        session.save()
        ...
```

The above example was gleaned from the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#example) on testing tools.

Comment: Why not set the session up under `setUp`?

Comment: @alias51 You can if you want. That's more of a style question. If they're making heavy use of one particular session key, then yes it should be done in the setup. If this is a one-off (maybe testing some kind of data being present for a single case), this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pytest` you can do the following:

```
import pytest

from django.test import Client

@pytest.mark.django_db # this is used if you are using the database
def test_my_tesst():
    # code before setting session
    c = Client()
    session = c.session
    session['var1'] = 'val1'
    session.save()
    # code after setting session
```

The most important is to save the session after changing it. Otherwise, it has no effect.